# How do I set color in my Line Chart Series the same color as specified cells?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to change Line Series color (the bottom one) into the colors those exist in Cells E4:N4.

My code returns only white color into all of my chosen Line Series. The data itself that forms the series in the chart (see pictures), I take from another Array (doesn't appear in the pictures).

Chart before I run my VBA:
[image: chart before I run my VBA]

Chart after I run my VBA:
[image: Chart after I run my VBA]

Is it because the code only returns the color of the data (array) that I choose to form the chart?

```vb
Sub lines_color()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    For i = 27 To 36
        For j = 5 To 15
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Cells(4, j + 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You likely want one loop here, not two.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the cells, and from their reference create the index of the series.
Something like this

```
Sub lines_color()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    
    For i = 4 To 9
        For j = 5 To 10
            iter= (i-4)*6+(j-4)
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iter).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Cells(i, j).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

If I don't find exactly the arrange of the series modify the iter equation according to it.